# Printing substring from one dataframe to another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe, substring

In the df_input['Visit'  ] column, there are three different timepoints that I would like to extract and have print into a new dataframe (df_output). The time points are Pre, Post, and Screening.

[image: data_input]

[image: data_output]

I essentially would like to make a for loop (or just a single code strand) stating:

if data_input['Visit  '] contains the word "Pre", print "Pre" in df_output['VISIT']
elif data_input['Visit  '] contains the word "Post", print "Post" in df_output['VISIT']
else data_input['Visit  '] contains the word "Screening", print "Screening" in df_output['VISIT']

I am just not sure of the proper way to do that.

So far, the only thing I have is this line of code:

*df_output['VISIT'] = df_input[df_input['Visit  '].str.contains('Pr|Po|Sc'))*

that gives the error message "Columns must be the same length as key"

I've also tried: *df_output['VISIT'] = df_input['Visit  '].str.contains('Pr|Po|Sc')*, which prints True or False into my output dataframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use np.select

```
import numpy

df_output['VISIT'] = np.select( [df_input['Visit'].str.contain('Pr'), # condition #1
                                df_input['Visit'].str.contain('Po'),  # condition #2
                                df_input['Visit'].str.contain('Sc')], # condition #3
                                ['Pre','Post','Screening'], # corresponding value when true
                                '')# default value
```

Comment: Would there be a way to add the hour value if it exists? So it would read:
Pre
2hr Post
Screening
2 hr Post
24 hr Post

Comment: yes. one way is to rsplit the Visit, one time and extract the hour to append to the output_visit. If you post a reproducible example, I'll be able to do that. Perhaps, post a separate question altogether. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

```
df_output['VISIT'] = df_input['Visit'].apply(lambda x: 'Pre' if x.str.contains('Pre') else 'Post' if x.str.contains('Post') else 'Screening' if x.str.contains('Screening') else "")
```

You must create df_ouput first, tho.

Comment: sorry i did not mention it in the original post; df_output was created.